# saving array of string and integers to a text file in python

Tags: python, string, numpy, text

I have a python list

```
temp = [['abc.jpg', 1, 2, 3, 'xyz'], ['def.jpg', 4,5,6, 'xyz']]
```

To save it as an array, so I do this:

```
temp = np.vstack(temp)
```

Result:

```
print(temp)
temp = [['abc.jpg', '1', '2', '3', 'xyz'], ['def.jpg', '4','5','6', 'xyz']]
```

It is converting the integers to string. I dont want that to happen.

I want to save the result in a text file.

I tried the following:

```
np.savetxt("data.txt", temp)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U8') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

Comment: A string array like this has to be saved with `%s` format.  To retain more control on the display of numbers you need to create a structured array, which can be saved with `savetxt`.  The `duplicate` sort-of helps with the structured array, but does not use `savetxt`.  I'm sure there are newer better duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this(it saves every row separated by ";"):

```
 np.savetxt("data.txt", temp, delimiter=" ", newline = "\n", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: That gives a one line file with `abc.jpg 1 2 3 xyz;def.jpg 4 5 6 xyz;`

Comment: @Bart how do you want to save?

Comment: np.savetxt("data.txt", temp, delimiter=" ", newline = "\n", fmt="%s") - this saves in new line. Works perfectly for me! Thanks

Comment: @Blue; which python/numpy/.. version? In my case (Python 3.6, Numpy 1.13) your solution does work (without converting `1` to `"1"`)

Comment: using 3.5.3 python version and 1.13.3 numpy version. I turned my list into an array with `temp = np.array(temp)`. Upon printing it I get `temp = [['abc.jpg', '1', '2', '3', 'xyz'], ['def.jpg', '4','5','6', 'xyz']]` but when I open the textfile there are no strings. It is saved as `abc.jpg 1 2 3 xyz def.jpg 4 5 6 xyz`